Unable to create a tree view in reactjs
I am trying to create a treeview in React.js. But I am not able to set it properly. Below is my code
App.js
import React from "react";
import TreeHierarchy from "./TreeHierarchy"; // Adjust path if necessary

const App = () => {
return (
<div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
  <h1>Bahria Hierarchy</h1>
  <TreeHierarchy />
</div>
);
};

export default App;

TreeHierarchy.js
import React from "react";
import { TreeView, TreeItem } from "@mui/x-tree-view";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight";

// Sample hierarchy
const hierarchy = {
name: "Bahria",
precincts: [
{
  name: "Precinct-1",
  streets: [
    {
      name: "Road 1",
      meters: ["3092000001", "3092000210"],
    },
    {
      name: "Street 21",
      meters: ["3092000012"],
    },
    ],
    },
    ],
 };

// Recursive function to render the hierarchy tree
const TreeHierarchy = () => {
const renderTree = (node, parentId = "") => {
const nodeId = `${parentId}-${node.name || "node"}`;

return (
  <TreeItem key={nodeId} nodeId={nodeId} label={node.name || "Unnamed"}>
    {node.streets &&
      node.streets.map((street, index) =>
        renderTree(street, `${nodeId}-street-${index}`)
      )}
    {node.precincts &&
      node.precincts.map((precinct, index) =>
        renderTree(precinct, `${nodeId}-precinct-${index}`)
      )}
    {node.meters &&
      node.meters.map((meter, index) => (
        <TreeItem
          key={`${nodeId}-meter-${index}`}
          nodeId={`${nodeId}-meter-${index}`}
          label={`Meter: ${meter}`}
        />
      ))}
  </TreeItem>
);
};

return (
<TreeView
  defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
  defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
>
  {renderTree(hierarchy)}
</TreeView>
);
};

export default TreeHierarchy;

Output

When I click on the main node name I am getting below errors
MUI X: The Tree View component requires all items to have a unique `id` property.
Alternatively, you can use the `getItemId` prop to specify a custom id for each item.
Two items were provided with the same id in the `items` prop: "undefined"
Error: MUI X: The Tree View component requires all items to have a unique `id` property.
Alternatively, you can use the `getItemId` prop to specify a custom id for each item.
Two items were provided with the same id in the `items` prop: "undefined"
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15169:15
at basicStateReducer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37272:45)
at updateReducer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37381:26)
at updateState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37667:14)
at Object.useState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38464:20)
at Object.useState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:54836:25)
at useTreeView (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16177:64)
at SimpleTreeView (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12473:83)
at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37072:22)
at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40321:24)

The tree structure is below
Bharia (Parent node)
  => Precinct (value)
      =>streets (value)
         => meters (value)

I am stuck to it and must be missing something. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Isn't the error clear enough? You can read item identifer from Tree view docs.

Each TreeItem needs a unique itemId
... as stated in the documentation.
This is the changed renderTree function that respects this requirement:
const renderTree = (node, parentId = "") => {
  const nodeId = `${parentId}-${node.name || "node"}`;

  return (
    <TreeItem
      key={nodeId}
      // itemId added here
      itemId={nodeId}
      nodeId={nodeId}
      label={node.name || "Unnamed"}
    >
      {node.streets &&
        node.streets.map((street, index) =>
          renderTree(street, `${nodeId}-street-${index}`)
        )}
      {node.precincts &&
        node.precincts.map((precinct, index) =>
          renderTree(precinct, `${nodeId}-precinct-${index}`)
        )}
      {node.meters &&
        node.meters.map((meter, index) => {
          // an `id` constant to avoid repeating code
          const id = `${nodeId}-meter-${index}`;
          return (
            <TreeItem
              key={id}
              // ...and another itemId here
              itemId={id}
              nodeId={`${nodeId}-meter-${index}`}
              label={`Meter: ${meter}`}
            />
          );
        })}
    </TreeItem>
  );
};

In the code above, I've added a unique itemId property to each TreeItem.
I've also added an id constant in your node.meters.map(...) function argument, to avoid repeating the template string literal.

You are a life savor

@Moeez, if an answer solves your question, please feel free to accept and/or upvote it.
